# React Table not updating its values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, jsx, react-table

I'm having an issue with a ReactTable when clicking the Back (anterior) or Next (siguiente) buttons. Since data appears dynamically, I've implemented filters in this table to check numbers, etc.
When I click any button (back or next) the table doesn't change to the next 20 (for ex.) documents that are getting into the table. But when the rows (20 more, 50 or 100 more), all the documents appear.

Whats happening?

Here are images of whats happening:

This is the first image, nothing wrong:

[image]

If I click the Next (siguiente) button, nothing happens:
[image]

If I add more lines (30 Filas) the documents work as expected:
[image]

My table:

```
             <ReactTable
                previousText={"Anterior"}
                nextText={"Siguiente"}
                rowsText={"Filas"}
                pageText={"Página"}
                ofText={"de"}
                  style={{
                    "tableLayout": "fixed"
                  }}
                  data={surveys}
                  pages={total_pages}
                  page={page-1}
                  manual
                  sortable
                  filterable

                  columns={[

                    {
                      Header: props => <span><button className="fa-btn"><i className="fas fa-sort-alpha-up"></i></button>Nombre de Cliente</span>,
                      accessor: "client_name",
                      width: "20%",
                      filterable: false,
                    },
                    {
                      id: 'surveys.survey_record.recommendation', // Required because our accessor is not a string
                      Header: props => <span><button className="fa-btn"><i className="fas fa-sort-numeric-up"></i></button>CSAT</span>,
                      // accessor: d => d.surveys.survey_record.recommendation,
                      width: "20%",
                      Cell: props => <>{props.original.surveys.survey_record.recommendation}</>,
                      Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) =>
                        <select
                          className="select-dropdown"
                          onChange={  event =>{onChange(event.target.value)}}
                          style={{ width: "100%" }}
                          value={this.state.survey_recomendacion}
                        >
                          <option value="all">Todas</option>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>

                        </select>
                    },
                    {
                      id: 'surveys.survey_record.satisfaction',
                      Header: props => <span><button className="fa-btn"><i className="fas fa-sort-numeric-up"></i></button>NPS</span>,
                      // accessor:  d => d.surveys.survey_record.satisfaction,
                      width: "20%",
                      Cell: props => <>{props.original.surveys.survey_record.satisfaction}</>,
                      Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) =>
                        <select
                          className="select-dropdown"
                          onChange={event =>{onChange(event.target.value)}}
                          style={{ width: "100%" }}
                         value={this.state.survey_satisfaccion}
                        >

                          <option value="all">Todas</option>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                          <option value="6">6</option>
                          <option value="7">7</option>
                          <option value="8">8</option>
                          <option value="9">9</option>
                          <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                    },
                    {
                      Header: "Comentarios",
                      accessor: "survey.cometarios",
                      width: "30%",
                      Cell: props => <>{props.original.surveys.survey_record.comments}</>,
                      filterable: false,
                    },
                    {
                      Header: "Conversación",
                      width: "20%",
                      Cell: props => <button onClick={() => this.handleTranscript(props.original.transcript)} className="button-style -text-table" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#conversationModal"><i className="fas fa-eye"></i> Mostrar</button>,
                      sortable: false,
                      filterable: false,
                    }
                  ]}

                  defaultPageSize={limit}
                  className="-striped -highlight"
                  expanded={this.state.expanded}
                  showPagination={true}
                  showPaginationTop={false}
                  showPaginationBottom={true}
                  pageSizeOptions={[20, 30, 50]}
                  onPageSizeChange={(pageSize, pageIndex) => {
                    if (surveys_answered > total_pages) {
                      this.setState({
                        limit: pageSize,
                        page: pageIndex + 1
                      }, this.apiSurveys)
                    }
                  }}
                  onPageChange={pageIndex => {
                    pageIndex === 0 ? pageIndex = 1 : pageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
                    this.setState({
                      page: pageIndex,
                    }, this.apiSurveys);

                  }}
                  onSortedChange={(newSorted, column, shiftKey) => {
                    if (this.state.descending_sorts.includes(column.id)){
                      this.setState({
                        descending_sorts: [],
                        ascending_sorts: [column.id]
                      }, this.apiSurveys)
                    } else {
                      this.setState({
                        descending_sorts: [column.id],
                        ascending_sorts : []
                      }, this.apiSurveys)
                    }
                  }}
                  onFilteredChange={(filtered, column) => {
                    let self = this;
                    filtered.forEach(function (element) {
                      if(element.id === "surveys.survey_record.satisfaction"){
                        self.setState({
                          survey_satisfaccion: element.value

                        }, self.apiSurveys);
                      }

                      if(element.id === "surveys.survey_record.recommendation"){
                        self.setState({
                          survey_recomendacion: element.value
                        }, self.apiSurveys);
                      }
                    });
                  }}
                  noDataText={"No se encontraron encuestas..."}
                />
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, you might have a “redeclaration” issue within your “onPageChange” function... try changing this: “ pageIndex === 0 ? pageIndex = 1 : pageIndex = pageIndex + 1;” to this “ pageIndex = pageIndex === 0 ? 1 : pageIndex + 1;

Comment: Hi @AndresO.Serrano, thanks for answering. Still not working.

Comment: Bummer, sorry. I wonder if you need to kick off the